# Roaming Extensions with Asterisk

Tags: load-balancing, asterisk

I've done some preliminary searches but I have not found anything about how roaming extensions could be done.

Basically I'd like the ability to have Asterisk servers geographically distributed and/or have multiple servers in a single location and round robin user connections to them appropriately.

If two servers both have an extension '1000', and that user connects to Server A, then a user on Server B tries calling, is there a way for server B to realise that '1000' isn't connected to them and try the other server?

I'm looking at possibilities for both fault tolerance and minimising ping times when people are all around the country. It seems like it would have lots of applications.

I'm not interested in a active-passive cluster, nor actually assigning extensions to specific servers geographically. Ideally any extension should be able to connect to any server and call any other extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) followme(if extension not present, dial other server)

2) DUNDI protocol. It designed to track such users.

Comment: Ahh DUNDi looks like what I was missing. Not sure why my searches didn't show it.